# neo4j apoc.algo.dijkstra '<' or '>' or '|' indicators

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

In the neo4j APOC procedures there's `apoc.algo.dijkstra` algorithm and it is structured like: `apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, end, 'RELATIONSHIP', 'attribute')`, and I know that in the `RELATIONSHIP` argument you can include things like  '<' or '>' or '|' indicators. But I do not know what they mean or what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of that parameter is relationshipTypesAndDirections.
< means incoming relationship, > means outgoing relationship, | is the OR logical operator.

For example:

```
KNOWS|<WORKS_WITH|IS_MANAGER_OF>
```

That means the pathfinding algorithm will look for KNOWS relationship in any direction, incoming WORKS_WITH relationship, or outgoing IS_MANAGER_OF relationship.

Comment: Is it purposeful that you put the < at the start of WORKS_WITH and the > at the end of IS_MANAGER_OF ? Or could you put it anywhere?

Comment: For me, it makes sense to use this way logically. But you can use anywhere, it has the same meaning. You can find examples here in the code:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/d822de07a54a53a5e22168f3c7274e78cf509496/src/test/java/apoc/path/RelationshipTypeAndDirectionsTest.java#L29